# Problem in query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I have a table called `album` with the following columns:

```
Album_Id, User_Id, Report_Id, PhotoName
```

There are different `Photoname` on a `User_Id` and `Report_Id` combination

Like:

```
Album_Id   User_Id    Report_Id       PhotoName
1          1          16              A.jpg
2          1          16              B.jpg
3          2          17              C.jpg
4          2          17              D.jpg
```

**I just want to retrieve data in format**

```
User_Id    Report_Id       PhotoName1     PhotoName2
 1          16              A.jpg          B.jpg  
 2          17              C.jpg          D.jpg
```

Max Photos are 4...

Comment: and where is the question ? what did you try ? what did not work ?

Comment: Are there always only 2 photos per user? What if there are 100 - you want 100 columns w/ PhotoName### returned? Why?

Comment: "2          17              C.jpg          D.jpg" - what's the logic? You take ONE of the 2 report_id, and put both photos in different columns. And what if there are 3 photos? This example leaves a lot of questions. Please specify.

Comment: What logic did you use to return Report_Id = 17 in row #2 of your results instead of 12? Just seems like this field is unecessary.

Comment: @Jeff - Good spot but seems like a typo as they talk about `User_Id, Report_Id` combinations. @Supriya Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY User_Id, Report_Id ORDER BY Album_Id ) AS RN
               FROM     T
             )
    SELECT  User_Id ,
            Report_Id ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN PhotoName
                END) AS PhotoName1 ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN PhotoName
                END) AS PhotoName2 ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN PhotoName
                END) AS PhotoName3 ,
            MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN PhotoName
                END) AS PhotoName4
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY User_Id ,
            Report_Id
```

Comment: Edited to add in cols for 3/4 and you were missing the FROM ;)

Comment: @Supriya - No problems. If it worked for you hit the tick mark to the left of the answer to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Hi, I used your solution in my project, but now I faced another  problem that it was working fine when there was not much data in table but now when there are around 3000 records in table,query is responding too slow.Kindly give me some solution for this so that it could run fastly......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.User_Id, a.Report_Id, a.PhotoName as 'PhotoName1', a2.PhotoName as 'PhotoName2', a3.PhotoName as 'PhotoName3', a4.PhotoName as 'PhotoName4'
FROM album a
    LEFT JOIN album a2 on a2.User_Id = a.User_Id and a2.Report_Id = a.Report_Id AND a2.Album_Id != a.Album_Id
    LEFT JOIN album a3 on a3.User_Id = a.User_Id and a3.Report_Id = a.Report_Id AND a3.Album_id NOT IN (a.Album_Id, a2.Album_Id)
    LEFT JOIN album a4 on a4.User_Id = a.User_Id and a4.Report_Id = a.Report_Id AND a4.Album_id NOT IN (a.Album_Id, a2.Album_Id, a3.Album_Id)
ORDER BY a.User_Id, a.Report_Id ASC;
```